# Are more sports being watched due to more states legalizing sports betting and gambling?

Tags: betting

I've [read](https://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/2022/08/29/sports-betting-laws-by-state/) that there are many states in the US where you can now legally bet and gamble on sports. Each election term, it sounds like more states are voting on sports betting.

What impact has this had on the viewership of sports? Are more people watching or attending games due to sports betting?

Comment: States where? A significant proportion of the world's countries allow gambling as an industry with the same extent of regulation as financial markets and food retail. It's as legal to bet on a game as it is to buy shares or vodka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be the case that sports viewership numbers have increased since *Murphy* (which allowed states to legalize sports gambling in the US).  COVID of course made this a little complicated to measure, but [viewership has increased by several percent](https://www.ticketnews.com/2020/12/how-the-sports-betting-industry-affects-viewership-and-ticket-sales/) in the years since.

It also increases the viewership of games [during blowouts](https://variety.com/vip/the-state-of-online-sports-gambling-1235228711/), which obviously makes their eyes more valuable to advertisers (who otherwise would see a drop in viewers when the game is no longer remotely in doubt).

The exact numbers are hard to say, because so many confounding factors exist, but for example the [NFL ratings rose 5% in 2019](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/12/05/giants-co-owner-sports-betting-has-big-influence-on-nfl-ratings.html), the first year of legalized sports betting (in 13 states by that point).  That was pre-COVID, so avoids some of the other confounding factors there, but of course there could be other factors affecting it.